# Hausdorff distance loss in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

What is the most efficient way to implement a loss function that minimizes the pairwise Hausdorff distance between two batches of tensors in Tensorflow?.

Comment: Late response - but I have an implementation of the weighted Hausdorff loss (https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07564) in Keras if anyone else stumbles upon this problem: https://github.com/danielenricocahall/Keras-Weighted-Hausdorff-Distance-Loss/tree/master/CustomLosses